# How many key-value entries can be stored in Solidity Mapping data structure?

Tags: solidity, storage, mapping

```
mapping(uint => uint) public myMap;

function store(uint key, uint val) public {
   myMap[key]=val;
}

function retrieve(uint key) public view returns (uint){
    return myMap[key];
}
```

Considering the above code, if we assume the size of uint is 256 bits(or 32 bytes), then can we store all possible 2^256 entries as key values in the mapping? each of these 2^256 can hold a uint value. So, the total space requirement to store the entire mapping data structure is (2^256)*32 bytes. Right? Since the state variables are stored in the blockchain itself, how it is possible to allocate and store such a huge memory in blockchain? What is the mechanism?

I have read an article, where it says for storage type state variables like mapping, we can populate a single entry (i.e. key-value pair). Only the caller need to pay the gas cost associated with a single entry writing. It also takes memory space for a single entry in the BC.

So, if that is the case- Can't I populate a mapping data structure using a loop(say, 10 lakhs entries in one go)? because then it consumes a huge gas cost? right? for e.g. the below code will not run due to excessive gas cost.

for(uint i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
myMap[i]=2*i;
}

*How many entries can be populated at max in a single go using a loop?

But if I can populate a single entry every time(by calling the store function, mentioned above) and calling this function for 10 lakhs times, hopefully, this will work. Isn't it?

I am a little bit confused, please help me to understand the concept.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of your research?

Comment: I am developing a DAPP, where I need to store a huge no of entries in a mapping (i.e. key-value pair). I can't run a loop to populate the entries due to gas cost restrictions. What is the alternative way to do the same? and also I would like to know, the mechanism/technology that solidity uses to store these kinds of data structures like mapping, array, etc (which are declared as state variables with the "storage" keyword) in Ethreum Blockchain.

Comment: For Solidity, it is necessary to develop algorithms that do not require iterative processing of large arrays. Or develop a process so that the corresponding functionality is brought to the Oracle. Or change the blockchain platform to some other one whose smart contracts better support iterative processing of large arrays.

Comment: You can store as much as you want in a mapping, as long you pay gas for it. Each store is going to cost 20,000 gas. You can compute what would be a practical number that you would want to store. Also note that `2**256` is an obscenely large number. Even theoretically, you would have issues with `keccak256` hash collision invalidating data in your mapping for such large numbers.

Comment: Thanks Mad Jackal, hrkrshnn for your time.